# Using the ValidateModelAttribute with an MVC View in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Previously in WebAPI projects I used the `ValidateModelAttribute` to avoid repeating `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` statements in each of my controllers.

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
  {
    if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to use the same attribute on an action in a MVC controller (ASP.NET Core 2.1) I receive a 400 status code and the page simply displays the JSON representation of the error e.g. `{"Description":["Description is required"]}`.

Is there a similar attribute I can use in my MVC controllers to forward the ModelState errors to my view in the same way as using

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  return View(command);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. The problem with returning a `ViewResult` is that you need to return the "model" with it, in order for everything to bind up properly to refill the form fields and display validation error messages. That model is some param on your action, but it will be different from action to action and may exist with other params, making it difficult if not impossible to discern which is the "model" that should be returned. In short, it's easy for you to do something like `return View(model)`; it would be difficult if not impossible to instruct an automated process to do it correctly in every instance.

In APIs, you get to sidestep all this because you're just returning simple JSON and you can use `ModelState` to get all the info you need to return an object with a list of validation errors. What "model" was posted is entirely inconsequential.

Also, for what it's worth, in ASP.NET Core 2.1, you don't even need your custom attribute for this. All you have to do is decorate your controller with `[ApiController]`. ASP.NET Core, then, will automatically return an `BadRequestObjectResult` (400) composed from `ModelState` if there's any validation errors.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will have to go back to adding it to each action